# @RefreshScope seems to ignore Mockito's mocks

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, mockito, spring-cloud

I'm implementing a service using Spring Boot and Spring Cloud Config service to provide the configuration values. In my Service I have a couple of config values which need to refresh when the value changes in the remote Git repo, and I was using `@RefreshScope` to enable that feature.

The problem comes when I try to inject a mock for `RestTemplate` in that service, it appears to ignore it and use the autowired instance instead. If I comment out the annotation it seems to work fine.

Here's the code for the Service:

```
@Service
@RefreshScope
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MyServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    public RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Value("${opts.default}")
    private String default;

    @Value("${opts.address}")
    private String address;

    @Value("${opts.separator}")
    private String separator;

    ...


  }
```

Test source code:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
public class ServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    @InjectMocks
    private MyServiceImpl service;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    public void testMethod() throws Exception {
        when(restTemplate.postForObject(anyString(), any(), eq(ServiceResponse.class), anyMap())).thenReturn(getSuccessfulResponse());

        ServiceResponse response = service.doYourStuff();

        Assert.assertNotNull(response);
        Assert.assertTrue(response.isSuccessful());
    }

    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When adding the `@RefreshScope` the bean becomes a proxy instead of an actual raw implementation. Currently the `RestTemplate` is set on the proxy rather then the underlying instance. (If you debug you would see that your `MyServiceImpl` is actually more like an instance of `MyServiceImpl$SpringCgLib#353234`).

To fix you need to manually set the dependency using `ReflectionTestUtils` and `AopTestUtils`. The latter is to obtain the actual proxy.

Remove the `@InjectMocks` annotation and add the following to your `setup` method after the initialization of the mocks:

```
Object actualTarget = AopTestUtils.getUltimateTargetObject(service);
ReflectionTestUtils.setfield(actualTarget, "restTemplate", restTemplate);
```

For versions earlier as 4.2 the following might do the trick

```
Object actualTarget = (service instanceof Advised) ? ((Advised) service).getTargetSource().getTarget() : service;
```

The problem is that Mockito doesn't detect the proxy and just sets the field. The `ReflectionTestUtils` doesn't detect the proxy either hence the manual unwrapping. I actually stepped into this trap a couple of times before, which led me to create [SPR-14050](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14050) this morning to have it embedded in the `ReflectionTestUtils` to easy the pain a little.

Comment: Thanks! I added myself as a watcher to that issue

Comment: Btw, is AopTestUtils the class you use instead of AopUtils?

Comment: Spring-cloud Angel.SR6 uses Spring 4.1.9 which doesn't include that class. AopTestUtils was introduced in Spring 4.2.0, is there any alternative for previous versions?

Comment: Copy the code I guess... The problem is you need the unwrapped instance, `AopUtils` and `AopProxyUtils` only detect the type however that won't help here as you need the object  not only the type. I added another code snippet which might help...

Comment: Sorry: Could not find field [restTemplate] of type [null] on target [class service.impl.MyServiceImpl]

Comment: It seems the code you added last should be the other way around, if it's an instance of Adviced, then return it, otherwise, cast. Once done it, it successfully injects the mock but when I get to the method, it has already replaced the mocked instance for the real one again T_T

Comment: No it shouldn't... If it is an instanceof `Advised` you want the internal object else return...

Comment: Ok it injects it in the inner object, the original service object shows it as null though. Anyway when it gets to the method it injects the autowired one overwriting the mock.